# Have an issue with access to Google Web App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-settings-api

I tried to find the answer to this question. I've combed forums and stackoverflow and I'm still at a loss for how to get a web app to work outside of my own domain.

**Change Admin Share Settings**

I've read here and in other places go to Admin Console > Apps > Drive and Docs > Sharing Options

All the ones mentioned are checked:

- "Invitations to people outside of domain who are not using a google account"
- "Allow users in domain to publish files visible to the world as public or unlisted"

**Publishing App**

Made sure to avoid these pitfalls:

- "Anyone, even anonymous"
- Execute the app as "Me"
- Made sure to create a new web app to avoid the caching issues

Yet I still cannot see it if not logged in as a user attached to the domain. It's just a simple "hello world" test to simplify the code, but I still get blocked. Seeing..

[image: Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again. Get stuff done with Google Drive..]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you to the community for all the other answers that at least put me to knowing most of the potential issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I'm at fault. It's never user error, right?! You can't just copy the web URL at this stage:

[image: Deploy as web app]

You have to go to it then copy the redirected URL for anonymous access.

My redirect URL looked more like https://script.google.com/a/macros/...

Comment: You can also get it with `var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();`

Comment: @Cooper thank you! That is really helpful as well. Thought I was going crazy for a minute on this. It worked then it didn't, but when you have multiple google accounts things get confusing fast.